# jquery submit failure

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'm trying to submit a form by assigning submit() to a click handler in jquery. My code is currently this:

```
$("#ics_alert_submit").click(function()
{ 
$("#ICS_upload_form").submit();
}
);
```

where #ics_alert_submit is a button in a jquery generated modal window and #ICS_upload_form is the id and name of the form I wish to submit.
I can't see any reason why this isn't working. Have I missed something really obvious?!?!

Comment: you should post the html also :) From top of my head, it could be, that you have `form name="ICS_upload...` and not `form id="ICS_upload...`

Comment: @Adam: the OP says "the id and the name of the form".

Comment: Please, could include the html with a form and button

Comment: @cletus: that I overlooked... But still, my main point was to include the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"...where **#ics_alert_submit is a button in a jquery generated** modal window..."

How is the submit button being generated? If it is not present when the page loads, the the click() event isn't getting attached.

If that's the case, you would need:

```
$("#ics_alert_submit").live('click', function() { 
    $("#ICS_upload_form").submit();
});
```

This will look for #ics_alert_submit to be dynamically added to the DOM, and will attach the event when added.

Comment: this is probably it. hopefully, the OP will clarify.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Of course. I knew it would be something simple I'd overlooked! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

without having the actual HTML this function is supposed to work on, the only thing I could suggest is look out for case-sensitivity in HTML id names and class names. You have "#ics_alert_submit" as the button, but "#ICS_upload_form" as the form. Make sure the cases match, as outlined here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/casesensitivity#